# Can I point /etc directory somewhere else when I run a specific program

Tags: linux, mount

Suppose I have a custom binary on Linux that references `/etc/mybinary/my.conf` file.

I can not change the binary, nor the config file, is it possible to fool the binary to look into my `/home/hari/etc` directory instead of  `/etc/mybinary` folder when I run the binary.  Maybe mount over the folder somehow prior to running it?

Comment: What custom binary? Who gave you it to you? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57559733/edit) your question to improve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't change the ... config file"?  If you have permissions to add a mount, then you probably have permission to make /etc/mybinary a symbolic link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom program might accept some program option (or some environment variable) to override its configuration file. [Try to run](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) `yourcustomprogram --help` to find out (then `man yourcustomprogram`) and read its documentation.

And you might consider using a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/50557) (or a symbolic link) to solve your issue. See also [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)

Comment: Thank you,it looks like bind mount is what I need.  Unfortunately I don't have root access on the box.  Is there a way to go around it?  I was hoping for docker, but that's also not available.

Comment: You can do it with `fakechroot`

Comment: Are unprivileged user namespaces enabled (try `unshare -rm`)? Is `bwrap` (package: bubblewrap) installed setuid root?

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variable to the main TOP directory from where config file is available
For example
before running set TOPDIR=/home/hari
and in your program read the environment variable TOPDIR and get config file from that path. ($TOPDIR/etc/mybinary/my.conf
If you can not change the code to modify binary, you can use softlink 
create a link from /home/hari/etc/my.conf -> /etc/mybinary/my.conf

Comment: This usage of `TOPDIR` environment variable might not work for every program (and does not work for the most programs I did write since 1987 on Unix or Linux)